# Contains or Regex in formula for checking multiple values

Tags: formula, regular-expressions, contains

I'm writing a formula to check of a field (for example, "Country"), contains one of many values.

Example:

```
CONTAINS(“Massadonia Republic:Dominican Republic:US:UK”,Country)
```

From what I'm told however, this will return true if the Country is just set to "Republic", without doing an exact match for the items delimited by colons.

To get an exact match, I'm told to use REGEX instead. The only issue is I can't find an example of a REGEX function for exact matching on multiple options.

Is there any way to do that in Salesforce?

Comment: If you know values never contain ":" you could do this using `CONTAINS(':Massadonia Republic:Dominican Republic:US:UK:', ':' + Country + ':')`.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple in regular expressions, both in Salesforce any pretty much wherever regular expressions are supported. Just use the `|` operator to specify full values:

```
REGEX(Country, "^(Massadonia Republic|Dominican Republic|US|UK)$")
```

Where:

- ^ indicates "from the start of the string"
- $ indicates "to the end of the string"
- () indicates a "group" (treated as a single token)
- | indicates "or"

Comment: I've tried this, but it gives a syntax error when using it in a Flow as the entry criteria.

Comment: @user1702965 For a flow, the field has to be in a merge field, such as: `REGEX({!varName.Country}, "^(Massadonia Republic|Dominican Republic|US|UK)$")`.

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm using -- still a syntax error.